# Solve 1004 Error problem with WorksheetFunction.VLookup (dynamic ranges)

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, vlookup

Thank you in advance for your help and understanding - currently, I'm making the first steps in VBA world :)

Every few days I receive the list of customers - I'm obliged to check if they're existing in our database. I've decided to create a simple macro based on the Vlookup function. The idea is quite simple - the macro will search for the customer in the table placed in the first sheet ("Database") and give the output in the second one ("Tool"). Both sheets are placed in the same workbook. What is noteworthy, the lookup range has some blank cells with no input in them.

However, when I try to execute the macro, it runs into a 1004 error (*Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class*). I've already tried switching WorksheetFunction.Vlookup to Application.Vlookup, but unfortunately it didn't help at all.

What's a good way to handle errors here?

```
Sub Macro()

Dim rng As Range
Dim FinalResult As Variant
Dim Table_Range As Range
Dim LookupValue As Range

Set rng = Sheets("Tool").Range("B:B") 'I've decided to use the entire column as a range because the number of customers to check is different every time
Set Table_Range = Sheets("Database").Range("C:H")
Set LookupValue = Sheets("Tool").Range("A:A") 
FinalResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LookupValue, Table_Range, 6, 0)
rng = FinalResult

End Sub
```

Comment: `LookupValue` must be a single value, not a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A VBA Lookup (`For Each...Next`, `Application.Match`)

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CustomersLookup()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Database" ' Worksheet Name
    Const sfRow As Long = 2 ' First Data Row
    Const slCol As String = "C" ' Lookup Column
    Const svCol As String = "H" ' Value Column
    
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Tool" ' Worksheet Name
    Const dfRow As Long = 2 ' First Data Row
    Const dlCol As String = "A" ' Lookup Column
    Const dvCol As String = "B" ' Value Column
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, slCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If slRow < sfRow Then Exit Sub
    Dim slrg As Range ' Source Lookup Range (Lookup Range)
    Set slrg = sws.Range(sws.Cells(sfRow, slCol), sws.Cells(slRow, slCol))
    Dim svrg As Range ' Source Value Range
    Set svrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(svCol)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dlCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If dlRow < dfRow Then Exit Sub
    Dim dlrg As Range ' Destination Lookup Range
    Set dlrg = dws.Range(dws.Cells(dfRow, dlCol), dws.Cells(dlRow, dlCol))
    ' Destination Value Range is handled per cell, using 'EntireRow'.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Loop and write.
    Dim dlCell As Range ' Destination Lookup Cell (Lookup Value)
    Dim dvCell As Range ' Destination Value Cell (Result)
    Dim srIndex As Variant ' Source Row Index (Row of the Match)
    Dim dString As String ' Lookup Value Converted to a String
    For Each dlCell In dlrg.Cells
        If Not IsError(dlCell) Then ' check if error value
            dString = CStr(dlCell.Value)
            If Len(dString) > 0 Then ' check if blank
                Set dvCell = dlCell.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol)
                ' Attempt to find a match.
                srIndex = Application.Match(dString, slrg, 0)
                If IsNumeric(srIndex) Then ' match found
                    dvCell.Value = svrg.Cells(srIndex).Value
                Else ' match not found
                    dvCell.Value = "Nope" ' or whatever
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next dlCell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Operation finished successfully.", vbInformation, "Customers Lookup"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Everything is working perfectly, thank you so much! To be quite frank, I didn't expect such a complex solution at all :)